# Getting the correct length to the zero height plane

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get the length from the camera's mouse input ray to where the height would be 0. Much like raycasting to a plane, but there is no physical plane, only a mathematical one. However, my ray created from the supposed length (red) keeps falling short or overshoots. Not sure what my code is doing wrong. For reference, the ball is at height 0. The blue line also stops at the correct location.

[image]

To replicate in Unity add this to code to a script and attach to any game object:

```
private void Update()
{
    // Get the mouse position in screen space.
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

    Vector3 vectorFromMouse = ray.direction;

    // Get Angle
    float angle = Vector3.Angle(vectorFromMouse, Vector3.down);

    if (angle >= 90)
    {
        return;
    }

    float y = ray.origin.y;

    float c = y / Mathf.Cos(angle);
    float a = y * Mathf.Tan(angle);
    float c2 = Mathf.Sqrt(a * a + y * y);
    Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, vectorFromMouse * c2, Color.red, 0.1f);
    Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, Vector3.down * y, Color.blue, 0.1f);

    print($"{angle} | {y} | {c} | {c2}");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use a mathematical [`Plane`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Plane.html) which already does all this math for you using [`Plane.Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Plane.Raycast.html)

```
var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
var plane = new Plane(Vector3.up, Vector3.zero);

if(plane.Raycast(ray, out var length))
{
    // you already have the length now
   
    // but I assume you actually also rather want the hit point
    var point = ray.GetPoint(length);

    Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, point, Color.red);
}
```

if you are really interested in the math behind it checkout the [source code](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/67d5d85abbea076e469a1642e04f3ab50a326bea/Runtime/Export/Geometry/Plane.cs#L124)

> ```
>     // Intersects a ray with the plane.
>     [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptionsEx.AggressiveInlining)]
>     public bool Raycast(Ray ray, out float enter)
>     {
>         float vdot = Vector3.Dot(ray.direction, m_Normal);
>         float ndot = -Vector3.Dot(ray.origin, m_Normal) - m_Distance;
>
>         if (Mathf.Approximately(vdot, 0.0f))
>         {
>             enter = 0.0F;
>             return false;
>         }
>
>         enter = ndot / vdot;
>
>         return enter > 0.0F;
>     }
> ```

Comment: Very close to working. Only thing that was off was that the second argument in the plane should have been `ray.origin.y` - otherwise it creates the plane at point of instantiation.

Comment: Well you said you wanted the zero plane which would be what I used in the code above .. the plane in XZ passing through origin ... if you use `ray.origin.y` (which is a float btw so you are rather using the constructor `Plane(Vector3 inNormal, float d)` where the distance is the distance from world origin along the normal (in your case Y-axis) to your camera Y ... => shouldn't make any difference at all except maybe the ray uses the camera near clipping plane ..?